hierarchical query in Oracle
I am trying to write a query to get continuous subscription date for members, but unable to pull for a scenario like below where end_date overlap for few date ranges for a member, please help to provide the logic/query in oracle.
Data in the Table



ID
Start_date
End_date




12345
07-Aug-15
07-Aug-65


12345
22-Aug-15
01-Jan-16


12345
24-Mar-16
23-Mar-66


12345
06-Jul-16
31-Dec-17


12345
31-Dec-16
31-Dec-41


46628
22-Aug-15
22-Dec-15


46628
01-Jan-16
01-Aug-18


46628
10-Jun-17
31-Dec-18


46628
01-Dec-18
04-Dec-72



Expected Data



ID
Start_date
End_date




12345
07-Aug-15
23-Mar-66


46628
22-Aug-15
22-Dec-15


46628
01-Jan-16
04-Dec-72



Below is the logic i am using, but its not giving expected result, please help.
    SELECT ID, 
        START_DATE, 
        END_DATE 
    FROM (
        SELECT ID,
            CONNECT_BY_ROOT START_DATE START_DATE,
            DAYS_DIFF, 
            END_DATE,
            PREV_END,
            CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF ISLEAF
        FROM ( 
            SELECT ID,
                DAYS_DIFF,PREV_END, START_DATE,END_DATE   
            FROM (   
                SELECT ID,
                    ROUND(START_DATE-PREV_END) DAYS_DIFF,
                    CASE 
                        WHEN START_DATE<=PREV_END THEN PREV_END 
                    END PREV_END, 
                    START_DATE,END_DATE
                FROM ( 
                    SELECT ID,
                        LAG(END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE) PREV_END, 
                        START_DATE,
                        END_DATE  
                    FROM TEST_TABLE A 
                )                  
            )     
        ) 
        CONNECT BY ID= PRIOR ID AND   PREV_END=  PRIOR END_DATE    START WITH PREV_END IS NULL  
    ) WHERE ISLEAF=1; 



Could you please provide logic to get expected result?

Please correct your example query, it's wrong

Use with Table1 as (// first base table query )   Table2 as (select * from Table1 with condition ) select * from table2 format
This will better understanding of a user

This is one query that could get your expected result
WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT 12345 AS id,     TO_DATE('07-Aug-15', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('07-Aug-65', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12345 AS id,     TO_DATE('22-Aug-15', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('01-Jan-16', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12345 AS id,     TO_DATE('24-Mar-16', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('23-Mar-66', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12345 AS id,     TO_DATE('06-Jul-16', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('31-Dec-17', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12345 AS id,     TO_DATE('31-Dec-16', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('31-Dec-41', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 4662828 AS id,   TO_DATE('22-Aug-15', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('22-Dec-15', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4662828 AS id,   TO_DATE('01-Jan-16', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('01-Aug-18', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4662828 AS id,   TO_DATE('10-Jun-17', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('31-Dec-18', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4662828 AS id,   TO_DATE('01-Dec-18', 'DD/MON/YY') AS Start_date,    TO_DATE('04-Dec-72', 'DD/MON/YY') AS End_date FROM dual 
)
, tmp1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT t.start_date AS start_date,
        t.id,
        t.start_date AS start_date1,
        t.end_date,
        level AS lvl
    FROM tmp t
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id AND PRIOR start_date <> start_date AND PRIOR end_date <> end_date 
        AND PRIOR end_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
)
, tmp2 AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tmp1
    WHERE (start_date, id, lvl) IN
        (
            SELECT start_date, id, MAX(lvl)
            FROM tmp1
            GROUP BY start_date, id
        )
)
SELECT id,
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
    end_date
FROM tmp2
GROUP BY id, end_date
ORDER BY id, start_date;




ID
START_DATE
END_DATE




12345
07-AUG-15
23-MAR-66


4662828
22-AUG-15
22-DEC-15


4662828
01-JAN-16
04-DEC-72



fiddle

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY start_date, end_date
         MEASURES
           FIRST(start_date) AS start_date,
           MAX(end_date) AS end_date
         PATTERN (overlapping* final_range)
         DEFINE overlapping AS NEXT(start_date) <= MAX(end_date)
       )

In earlier versions you can use:
SELECT id,
       MIN(dt) AS start_date,
       MAX(dt) AS end_date
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         SUM(group_change) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)
          AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           dt,
           CASE type * SUM(type) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt, type DESC, ROWNUM)
           WHEN 1
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END AS group_change
    FROM   table_name
           UNPIVOT (dt FOR type IN (start_date AS +1, end_date AS -1))
  )
)
GROUP BY id, grp

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, start_date, end_date) AS
  SELECT   12345, DATE '2015-08-07', DATE '2065-08-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   12345, DATE '2015-08-22', DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   12345, DATE '2016-03-24', DATE '2066-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   12345, DATE '2016-07-06', DATE '2017-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   12345, DATE '2016-12-31', DATE '2041-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4662828, DATE '2015-08-22', DATE '2015-12-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4662828, DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2018-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4662828, DATE '2017-06-10', DATE '2018-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4662828, DATE '2018-12-01', DATE '2072-12-04' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



ID
START_DATE
END_DATE




12345
2015-08-07 00:00:00
2066-03-23 00:00:00


4662828
2015-08-22 00:00:00
2015-12-22 00:00:00


4662828
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2072-12-04 00:00:00



fiddle

@MTO in the PATTERN section of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, what is the purpose of "final_range" ?

@KoenLostrie You want to match at least one row in every match. In every set containing overlapping rows there is always going to be a final row in the range which does not overlap with any future rows. The overlapping pattern greedily matches rows while there exists at least one row in that match that overlaps with the next (currently) unmatched row; the final_range pattern is that final next row that is overlapped by at least one of the previous overlapping matches but none of the previously matched overlapping rows nor the final_range row will overlap with any future rows.
